# Solve the equation: $p = 1+r+r^2+ \ldots+r^n$

Tags: summation-method

There is an equation:  $p = 1+r+r^2+ \ldots+r^n$.

The right side of this equation can reduce to $(r^n-1)/(r-1)$, 
but I cannot find the way to find a function of $r$ and $p$ such that $n = f(p, r)$, 
can someone know how to get this function.

Comment: Using log will get the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$p= \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$
$$r^n = p(r-1)+1$$

$$n = \frac{\ln (p(r-1)+1))}{\ln r}$$